# Free text search in sparql when you have multiword and scaping character

Tags: sparql, contain

I am wondering how I can use  in sparql query when I have a word like :
Robert J. O'Neill
I am looking for the resource that have the multiword unit with quota or unicode character in the Label property.

```
                 SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?abstract 
                 WHERE {?resource rdfs:label ?s.
                 ?s <bif:contains> "'Robert J. O'Neill'"
                 ?resource dbo:abstract ?abstract
                 }
                 '''
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Providing an example of code or even tries is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query that will return all the elements that have "Robert J. O'Neill" as label.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE 
{
    ?s rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER(regex(?label, "Robert J. O'Neill", "i"))
}
```

If you are sure that you need a specific string matching. This is faster :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE 
{
    ?s rdfs:label ?label .
    ?label bif:contains "Robert J. O'Neill"
}
```

But be aware that, Virtuoso for example doesnt support such a query because of the spaces in the string. So an alternative is to avoid it as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE 
{
    ?s rdfs:label ?label .
    ?label bif:contains "Robert" .
    FILTER (CONTAINS(?label, " J. O'Neill"))
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with <bif:contains>  beacause regex is slow?

Comment: Thanks, Is there any endpoint that support a query with spaces in the string?

Comment: I haven't tested other endpoints on this specific statement yet.

Answer (score 1):

I found following code faster that the regex:

```
SELECT ?s  WHERE { ?s  rdfs:label ?o FILTER ( bif:contains ( ?o, '"Robert" AND "J." AND "Neill"' ) ) }
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a possible variant of the provide answer.