# Matching two words together in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

How to List the laureate awards (given by their label) for which the description of the contribution (given by nobel:motivation) contains the word "human" together with the word "peace" (i.e., both words must be there).

I have use the bds:search namespace from [the the full-text search feature of Blazegraph](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/FullTextSearch).
After visiting this link i have composed this query 
[Free text search in sparql when you have multiword and scaping character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801621/free-text-search-in-sparql-when-you-have-multiword-and-scaping-character)

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bds: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search#>
PREFIX nobel: <http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/>

SELECT ?awards  ?description  
WHERE { 
  ?entity rdfs:label   ?awards  .
  ?entity nobel:motivation ?description  .
   FILTER ( bds:search ( ?description, '"human" AND "peace"' ) ) 
}
```

This query is returning me the following error on execution shown in image.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66C5y.png)
How to correct this query and get the desired result?
 You may take a look at the specification of this dataset or download an [RDF dump of the dataset](https://www.ida.liu.se/research/semanticweb/events/SemWebCourse2018/nobelprize.nt) 
[image]

Comment: ehm, your second link just shows solutions for the Virtuoso triple store but you have Blazegraph. That does not work, fulltext search is **not** standardized in SPARQL, so each triple store has it's own syntax. The engine in Blazegraph is based on Lucene, so you should try their syntax. If boolean queries aren't support, you can always rewrite it by doing `?description bds:search "human" . ?description bds:search "peace"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bds:search to search for "human" category.Then apply filter and contain function to "peace".

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bds: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search#>
PREFIX nobel: <http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/>
PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>

SELECT ?awards  ?description  
WHERE { 
  ?entity rdfs:label   ?awards  .
  ?entity nobel:motivation ?description  .
  ?description bds:search "human" .
  FILTER (CONTAINS(?description, "peace"))
}
```

Comment: I don't get it? why wouldn't you use just twice the fulltext index?